# search for blank messages in tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I try to search blank messages in svn log using tortoise svn. I use regex ^$ and set search type 'Messages'. But for some reason it returns me revisions with not blank messages. However there are some revisions with blank messages.

Is it correct behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been matching messages with multiple lines with atleast one of the lines being empty ( as `^`  and `$` mark start and end of **line** and there is no way to use multiline options). <strike>I don't see if there is a way to not show these with TortoiseSVN as the search is not really mean't to be very powerful</strike>. But it should still show the ones that really do have completely empty messages.

Update:

See if the following works for you:

```
!^.+$
```

(look for messages that do NOT have some non empty lines. Seems to work for me.)

Comment: @misha nesterenko - found a way. See the updated answer with the regex you can try.

Comment: `!^.+$` does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me the following regular expression works correctly (TortoiseSVN lists all commits with empty comments)

```
^[^.]$
```

Best regards

Comment: This regex *does* work for me!

Comment: ...though on a closer look it also returns any commits with *any* empty lines, so the commits aren't necessarily empty themselves

Answer (score 0):

In my repositories, now in 2024, the log messages in my repo have a leading space.
`^ $`
finds blanks message in my repos.

Using version:
TortoiseSVN 1.14.6, Build 29673 - 64 Bit , 2023/12/25 19:33:34

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35501841)